# django not able to save all incidents in database

Tags: django, django-database, django-datatable, django-database-functions

I have a working code which gets all incident details.
But i am unable to save complete data in database only the last record gets saved

```
def incidents(request):
incidentsServicenow = IncidentsServicenow()
c = pysnow.Client(instance='', user='', password='')

# Define a resource, here we'll use the incident table API
incident = c.resource(api_path='/table/incident')
print('incident', incident)
# Query for incidents with state 1
response = incident.get()
print('response', response)
# Iterate over the result and print out `sys_id` of the matching records.
ticket = []
for record in response.all():
    data = {
        'number': record['number'],
        'description': record['description'],
        'short_description': record['short_description'],
        'state': record['state'],
    }
    #print(record['number'])
    incidentsServicenow.number = data['number']
    incidentsServicenow.title = data['short_description']
    incidentsServicenow.description = data['description']
    incidentsServicenow.state = data['state']
    #ticket.append(data)
    print("storing data")
    incidentsServicenow.save()
return HttpResponse(ticket, content_type='application/json')
```

My model is

```
class IncidentsServicenow(models.Model):
number = models.CharField(max_length=32)
title = models.CharField(max_length=160)
description = models.TextField()
state = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'incidents_servicenow'
```

I need to save all the records in database

Comment: post full function

Comment: Can you check now please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create objects in the loop. From the code, I can see that you created the `incidentsServicenow` object is created outside the loop.

```
  for record in response.all():
    data = {
        'number': record['number'],
        'description': record['description'],
        'short_description': record['short_description'],
        'state': record['state'],
    }
    #print(record['number'])
    incidentsServicenow = IncidentsServicenow()
    incidentsServicenow.number = data['number']
    incidentsServicenow.title = data['short_description']
    incidentsServicenow.description = data['description']
    incidentsServicenow.state = data['state']
    ticket.append(data)
    print("storing data")
    incidentsServicenow.save()
return HttpResponse(ticket, content_type='application/json')
```

or you could do like this

```
   for record in response.all():
    data = {
        'number': record['number'],
        'description': record['description'],
        'short_description': record['short_description'],
        'state': record['state'],
    }
    #print(record['number'])
    incidentsServicenow = IncidentsServicenow(number=data['number'],
title=data['short_description'],description=data['description'],state=data['state'])
    ticket.append(data)
    print("storing data")
    incidentsServicenow.save()
return HttpResponse(ticket, content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below line inside for loop

```
incidentsServicenow = IncidentsServicenow()
```